# Unable to create a Database Recourse in Azure with a student starter account

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am unable to create a Database Recourse in my Azure Account, which I have registered a few years ago as Student Starter. Whenever I want to create it, it suggests that "Namespace **Minecraft.Storage** doesn't allow the action. The accepted Namespace list are Microsoft.Authorization,Microsoft.Billing,Microsoft.Features,microsoft.insights,Microsoft.NotificationHubs,Microsoft.Resources,Microsoft.Sql,Microsoft.Subscription,microsoft.support,microsoft.visualstudio,Microsoft.Web”。

It is quite werid that I am unable to create a database lonely, but it is possible to create a similar one with a almost deprecated model WebApp+SQL.

I am quite confused about whether is my account is not allowed to create free SQL database or it is because of something else.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Could you please check if you have registered the resource provide `Microsoft.Storage` in your subscription? if you do not register, please register it : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types

Comment: Did you renew your Student Starter?

Comment: "After you exhaust your available credit or reach the end of 12 months, your Azure subscription will be disabled. If you‘ve reached the end of your 12 months and are still a student, you‘ll be able to renew your Azure for Students offer. We’ll notify you shortly before your 12-month anniversary to let you know how to renew."

Comment: Hi WinfreSelon, If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all so much for answering! I think my account hasn't been renewed, though some of the service still work in it. It now appears as a free account.

Comment: My subscription doesn't contain `Microsoft.Storage`.@JimXu

Answer (score 0):

Just according what you said "I have registered a few years ago as Student Starter", we don't know when and where you register the account.

"After you exhaust your available credit or reach the end of 12 months, your Azure subscription will be disabled. If you‘ve reached the end of your 12 months and are still a student, you‘ll be able to renew your Azure for Students offer. We’ll notify you shortly before your 12-month anniversary to let you know how to renew. "

**Is Azure for Students Starter available internationally?**

Yes, it's available in all countries where Azure is commercially available (but doesn’t include sovereign cloud products in US Government, Azure China, and Azure Germany regions).

Ref:

1. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/students-starter-faq/
2. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0144p/

If all of these are not helpful for you, the best way is contact the Azure support:
[image]

Ref: [Create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request)

Comment: Thank you for your response!
I think my account is quite weird since although it does reach the end of 12 months, the subscription is not disabled.
I registered it when I teamed my friend to attend Imagine Cup at 2018 I think.
The reason why I don't use the support is that it require a subscription of support, which at least cost 29$ a month.

Comment: It now appears as a free account, which cannot use any resourse that may generate fee.

Comment: @WinfreSelon It sounds a little strange. What's the current subscription now, free or pay-as-you-go?

Comment: the current subscription is free, which means that I cannot create any resources that require fee @Leon Yue

Comment: @WinfreSelon I guess you free account is over 12 month for a long time,  and you didn't renew it every year. Maybe you need to think about  upgrade  it to pay-as-you-go subscription.

Comment: Thank you for response. I think I may need to renew it I guess or create another account based on my current student status.

In addition, I think there may be something that I would like to make sure in this question. Why can I create the sql resourse based on an out-dated template but not with the current sql resourse create template, since it seems that I am eligible to create a free sql database?

Comment: @WinfreSelon yeah, it's very hard for us to get the real reason. Please try it. The free account need renew every year.